# Writing pdf with pypdf2 gives error

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to write a simple script to merge two PDFs but have run into an issue when trying to save the output to disk. My code is

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog    

### Prompt the user for the 2 files to use via GUI ###
root = tk.Tk()
root.update()
file_path1 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")],
            )

file_path2 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")],
            )

###Function to combine PDFs###
output = PdfFileWriter()

def append_pdf_2_output(file_handler):
    for page in range(file_handler.numPages):
        output.addPage(file_handler.getPage(page))

#Actually combine the 2 PDFs###
append_pdf_2_output(PdfFileReader(open(file_path1, "rb")))
append_pdf_2_output(PdfFileReader(open(file_path2, "rb")))

###Prompt the user for the file save###
output_name = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile(
            defaultextension='pdf')

###Write the output to disk###
output.write(output_name)
output.close
```

The problem is that I get an error of

UserWarning: File  to write to is not in binary mode. It may not be written to correctly. [pdf.py:453] Traceback (most recent call last): File "Combine2Pdfs.py", line 44, in  output.write(output_name) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/pytho‌​n3.5/site-packages/P‌​yPDF2/pdf.py", line 487, in write stream.write(self.*header + b*("\n")) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: can you post full stacktrace, not just the message?

Comment: please don't post stack traces in the comment.  Your question has an "edit" link that lets you edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

I got it by adding mode = 'wb' to tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile. Now it's

```
output_name = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        mode = 'wb',
        defaultextension='pdf')
output.write(output_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename` instead of `tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile`. You just want the filename, not the file handler itself.

```
###Prompt the user for the file save###
output_name = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='pdf')
```

Comment: With that I got the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'" So then I added
`with open("output_name", 'wb') as save:
 output.write(save)`
which doesn't give any errors but doesn't write the pdf either.